# what is wrong with this js link code? the array should show its data but it gives undefined. I want to display data in two columns

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslink

```
(function () {

    var itemCtx = {};
    itemCtx.Templates = {};

        itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b>Announcements</b></div><table>";
        itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
        itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";



    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();


function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;


var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;


return "<tr><td><p><b>" + _announcementTitle + "</b></p></td></tr>";

}
```

---with this code m getting values row by row as below:

1)Book Your Summer Vacation Now

2)We were Recognized as Exceptional Service

3)Ancmnts

4)XYX

----but i need to display it side by side as

1)Book Your Summer Vacation Now          2)      We were Recognized as Exceptional Service

3)Ancmnts                                 4)    XYZ

so i have made some changes in the code and used an array for it, now m getting format as two columns but m not getting data as array value is displayed undefined.

```
(function() {
    var itemCtx = {};
    itemCtx.Templates = {};
    enter code here
    itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b>Announcements</b></div>";

    itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;

    itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);
})();


function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
    var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
    var _announcementID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var myArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myArray[i] = _announcementTitle;
    }

    return "<table><tr><td><p><b>" + myArray[i] + "</b></p></td><td><p><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + myArray[i + 1] + "</p></b></td></tr></table>";
}
```

Array value is not coming in its proper way,it is displaying undefined in in place of its value.

Result:

> Announcements
>
> undefined       undefined
>
> undefined       undefined
>
> undefined       undefined

Comment: Well, you are trying to access an element of `myArray` with `i` as an index, when you're out of the loop. The thing is that by the time you get out of the loop, `i` is equal to `5`, and I guess `myArray[5]` is `undefined`.

Comment: then what shud i do? myArray[5] is undefined,but why it is not displaying other values?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What I see is that `_announcementTitle` is always the same value, so you're creating an array with the same thing repeated 5 times. If you want five tables, then you can concatenate the HTML inside of your loop, and then return the whole string containing the tables, but every table would be the same (with the same title). Or maybe you're running your `ItemOverrideFun` inside of a loop in another part of your code and passing it a different `ctx` every time?

Comment: i have edited the question,pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to render list items from Announcements list horizontally, right?

The following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      Templates: {
           View: renderAnnouncementsView
      },

      ListTemplateType: 104

    });

});


function renderAnnouncementsView(rCtx)
{
    var listData = rCtx.ListData;
    var viewHtml ='';

    viewHtml = '<table><tr>';
    for (var idx in listData.Row) {
        var listItem = listData.Row[idx];
        viewHtml += '<td>';
        viewHtml += listItem.Title;
        viewHtml += '</td>';
    }
    viewHtml += '</tr></table>';
    return viewHtml;
}
```